# How to filter multiple values for same column

Tags: django, django-models

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User    
...
resolvers = User.objects.filter(groups__name = 'resolver')
```

above code is to filter user belongs to group resolver, in this I need to retrieve users those belongs to admin group as well.

I tried

```
resolvers = User.objects.filter(groups__name = 'resolver' or 'admin')
resolvers = User.objects.filter(groups__name = ('resolver','admin'))
```

both are failing, please help.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `__in`:

```
resolvers = User.objects.filter(groups__name__in = ('resolver','admin'))
```

or [`Q object`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects) to implement `OR` condition:

```
from django.db.models import Q
resolvers = User.objects.filter(Q(groups__name='resolver')| Q(groups__name='admin'))
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. 1st approach is working fine. 2nd approach is throwing - 'QuerySet' object is not callable

Comment: @user6941347 can you post full traceback?

Comment: @user6941347 second should work also. Probably you have variable named `Q` in your code which overrides django's `Q` object?

Comment: Yes, there was a temp variable in the name of Q. Renamed it, now both approach are working